# CSS regions: JS alternative while we wait for browser support

Tags: css, responsive-design

Does anyone know of an open source JS solution to replicate the [new "regions" css proposition put forward by Adobe?](https://opensource.adobe.com/web-platform/samples/css-regions/Documentation.html)

I would really like to be able to flow inline content from one region to another for the development of magazine-like responsive layouts. I've found 'columnizing' plugins that create columns without CSS but haven't been able to find anything that flows text from box to box.

Comment: i think performance cost _might_ be unacceptable for life apps. As **any** layout changes will require you to re-render the page.. Also, spec will probably change during this year, so its not particularly attractive project for good developers to work on, and thus i think we wont see good JS alternative, at least until 2013.

Comment: yes, with responsive or liquid layouts it seems that the page layout and content flowing are inseparable tasks -- the latter of which I don't fully understand how it works. I'm thinking of something like [treesaver] (http://treesaver.net/) ... if only the re-laying out rules were more transparent and thus easier to control. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

**First think in terms of what devices are being used the most in 2014 and beyond.**

1. Cellphone - Mainly Portrait Mode
2. Tablets - Portrait or Landscape Mode
3. Laptops, PC, TV - Landscape Mode

Responsive design and media queries already cater for most scenarios.
Float text blocks in larger modes but fit the text in the limited screen real estate in cellphones portrait mode.
2 x Columns in cellphones (which dominate already) portrait mode looks awful.

**Now css regions are only a spec**
It breaks the main rule of separating content from presentation by wanting to flow text through interlinking divs.
My suggestion is stick to responsive design which is supported everywhere already.

Adobe needs to make a lot of changes to expect the W3C to ever support it.
In its current form its completely disruptive to web design and will damage the html5 and css spec irrevocably.

**However** CSS exclusions (shaping areas) does have some merit (if it works with media queries) and perhaps Adobe and partners will find a workable solution for this feature sometime in the future.